# Google Visually Similar Image API

Tags: api, search

I know there is this link to find visually similar images to an uploaded picture
https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?site=search&sa=X&image_url=YOUR_IMAGE_URL

but is there also a way to get an API for the first result of the visually similiar image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sympathy what you need.

I try to use google cse but this is not supported similar images.

So, Next that I try, URL. 
But this is able to on the browser.

I just need result of simliar images and then I wish that result is visually.

So, 
you can use Vision API of Google.
This is very simple.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/